# excel name box not selecting range

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file with several sheets & around 100 ranges defined across the sheets. Usually I can go to any particular range by selecting that range in the drop down name box. This is now not happening, the range name are there but selecting some (not all) does not go to the range any more.
In the name manager all ranges appear & all are scoped to the workbook.

I made a very simple test file with just 2 sheets & one range on each sheet & that works fine.
I then saved my problem file to a new name & stripped it down to just 2 sheets with one range on each sheet & the problem is still there.
I tried this test file on another pc with the same 2016 software & also tried it on an older pc with Excel 2010, same result.
I believe that the range names conform to requirements & have no spaces etc.
I am new to this site & hope that someone can resolve this. I can supply 2 the test files if required

thanks

Comment: You are not giving us much to work with: What are the names and Refersto formulas of the defined Names that don't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Pleased to advise that someone has supplied an answer to this, details as follows.
The spreadsheet is in development stage & at time I had several new windows open across 2 monitors. Then after saving & closing the file, it appears that one of the windows had not closed correctly. 
Re opening the file a "1" was appearing after the excel file name & I had not noticed this.In this condition a second window was open but hidden & the file had the problems described above. 
Selecting view-unhide revealed the other window. 
I closed the second window & the file then behaved as expected.
I also think that this "hidden" window contributed to hyperlinks within the file not working.
So all good now, I hope that this may assist others who may have similar issues.